Convert an Angular Material M2 theme to M3
The documentation from the Angular Material team is rather scarce and missing crucial information on how to transition from M2 to M3 for an existing theme. In our situation we have the following code:
$green-palette: (
  50: #e7f7eb,
  100: #c5eace,
  200: #a0dcb0,
  300: #77d090,
  400: #57c578,
  // Main color:
  500: #33ba60,
  600: #2aaa56,
  700: #1f984a,
  800: #13873f,
  900: #00672b,
  contrast: (
    50: vars.$dark-primary-text,
    100: vars.$dark-primary-text,
    200: vars.$dark-primary-text,
    300: vars.$dark-primary-text,
    400: vars.$dark-primary-text,
    500: vars.$light-primary-text,
    600: vars.$light-primary-text,
    700: vars.$light-primary-text,
    800: vars.$light-primary-text,
    900: vars.$light-primary-text,
  ),
);

// And other palettes

We use these palettes in the theme configuration:
$primary-palette: mat.m2-define-palette(p.$green-palette, 500);
$accent-palette: mat.m2-define-palette(p.$orange-palette, 300, 200, 500);
$warn-palette: mat.m2-define-palette(p.$red-palette, 400, 300, 600);
$link-palette: mat.m2-define-palette(p.$blue-palette, 700, 400, 800);

$theme: mat.m2-define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $primary-palette,
      accent: $accent-palette,
      warn: $warn-palette,
    ),
    typography: t.$typography,
    density: 0,
  )
);

// Adjust background palette
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "status-bar", #e0e0e0);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "app-bar", #f5f5f5);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "background", #f6f6f6);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "hover", rgba(black, 0.04));
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "card", white);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "dialog", white);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "disabled-button", rgba(black, 0.12));
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "raised-button", white);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "focused-button", rgba(black, 0.12));
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "selected-button", #e0e0e0);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "selected-disabled-button", #bdbdbd);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "disabled-button-toggle", #eeeeee);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "unselected-chip", #e0e0e0);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "disabled-list-option", #eeeeee);
$theme: f.theme-background-change($theme, "tooltip", black);

// Adjust foreground palette
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "base", black);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "divider", rgba(black, 0.12));
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "dividers", rgba(black, 0.12));
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "disabled", rgba(black, 0.38));
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "disabled-button", rgba(black, 0.26));
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "disabled-text", v.$dark-disabled-text);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "elevation", black);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "hint-text", rgba(black, 0.38));
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "secondary-text", v.$dark-secondary-text);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "icon", v.$dark-secondary-text);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "icons", v.$dark-secondary-text);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "text", v.$dark-primary-text);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "slider-min", v.$dark-primary-text);
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "slider-off", rgba(black, 0.26));
$theme: f.theme-foreground-change($theme, "slider-off-active", rgba(black, 0.38));

See How to set background palette in custom theme of Angular Material? for more information on the theme-background-change and theme-foreground-change functions.
Also, the typography configuration is a whole other matter and I will not go into this.
The question is how can I convert this into a M3 theme? I can generate a theme configuration file using ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme but this will not match the current palettes at all as it will not use the current primary and secondary colors as-is but as some starting point.
Also, where should I define my changed foreground and background colors in the new M3 theme?

There is no direct schematic available to convert existing M2 themes to M3 themes. You will have to do it manually.

That I should do it by hand is obvious but is there some documentation on how to map the values from e.g. a M2 palette hue to a M3 palette hue?

As there is no guide to converting a palette from M2 to M3 I looked up the hue used (40 for light and 80 for dark themes) and changed the generated palettes to use the following format where #33ba60 is my primary color:
  primary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 30),
    20: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 20),
    25: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 15),
    30: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 10),
    35: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 5),
    40: #33ba60,
    50: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 10),
    60: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 20),
    70: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 30),
    80: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 40),
    90: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 50),
    95: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 55),
    98: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 58),
    99: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 59),
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  primary-dark: (
    0: #000000,
    10: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 70),
    20: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 60),
    25: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 55),
    30: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 50),
    35: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 45),
    40: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 40),
    50: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 30),
    60: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 20),
    70: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 10),
    80: #33ba60,
    90: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 10),
    95: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 15),
    98: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 18),
    99: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 19),
    100: #ffffff,
  ),


This is excellent, an inspired solution. Can the base color (#33ba60) be set as a constant up front, or as a mixin parameter? That would make a really nice template.

I've created a few functions that will do the calculation based on color, base index (e.g. 40) and the required index and can create the mapping based on a color, base index and list of indexes. I've made it so that it will always include 0 as black and 100 as white. I've no access to the code right now but can post it over the weekend if you like.

Also, I call the functions and dump the results to the console. Next I just copy and paste it in the right place so I see the colors and not the function call. Makes it a bit easier to select the proper hue if necessary.

Very clever, well done! This is the type of code that Angular Material ought to provide.

There is a schematic to generate a m3 theme.
The inputs are the primary colors of each palette (primary, secondary, tertiary) and some neutral colors.
It generates a single scss file which can be modified and integrated.

The schematic uses derived colors from those you provided. So this is only useful as a starting point but you still have to input all your own colors.

I found this:
You have to import the material3 Theme as shown below
import androidx.compose.**material3**.MaterialTheme

MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = AppColorScheme,
    typography = AppTypography,
    shapes = AppShapes
) {
    // M3 content
}

Hope this helps.
See also here

Sorry, but I’m not programming for android but an Angular application
